# need help about to write correctly a function to extract information

Tags: php

How to extract correctly the element below under foreach function. I try different way an I can extract element but not under `$product_option_value_data`.

I have this element

```
    $data['options'] = [];
    $products_option_value = [];

    foreach ($product_option_value as $products_value) {
      $product_option_value_data[] = ['products_option_value_id' => $products_value['products_option_value_id'],
                                      'option_value_id'         => $products_value['option_value_id'],
                                      'name'                    => $products_value['name'],
                                      'image'                   => $products_value['image'],
                                      'quantity'                => $products_value['quantity'],
                                      'subtract'                => $products_value['subtract'],
                                      'price'                   => $products_value['price'],
                                      'price_prefix'            => $products_value['price_prefix'],
                                      'weight'                  => $products_value['weight'],
                                      'weight_prefix'           => $products_value['weight_prefix'],
                                      'customers_group_id'      => $products_value['customers_group_id'],
                                      'products_option_model'    => $products_value['customers_group_id'],
                                      'option_tax_class_id'      => $products_value['customers_group_id']
      ];
    }

    $data['options'][] = [
      'products_option_id'    => $value['products_option_id'],
      'option_id'            => $value['option_id'],
      'name'                 => $value['name'],
      'type'                 => $value['type'],
      'value'                => $value['value'],
      'required'             => $value['required'],
      'products_option_value' => $product_option_value_data
    ];
  }
```

`$product_option_value_data` is an element can have some informations added under an array

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=13)
      'products_option_value_id' => string '171' (length=3)
      'option_value_id' => string '179' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
      'image' => null
      'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
      'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
      'price' => string '1.0000' (length=6)
      'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'customers_group_id' => string '99' (length=2)
      'products_option_model' => string '99' (length=2)
      'option_tax_class_id' => string '99' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=13)
      'products_option_value_id' => string '170' (length=3)
      'option_value_id' => string '180' (length=3)
      'name' => string 'M' (length=1)
      'image' => null
      'quantity' => string '100' (length=3)
      'subtract' => string '0' (length=1)
      'price' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
      'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'weight' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'weight_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
      'customers_group_id' => string '99' (length=2)
      'products_option_model' => string '99' (length=2)
      'option_tax_class_id' => string '99' (length=2)
```

I write a loop like that but it does'nt work, I can't extract the

`$product_option_value_data` element

```
      $options = $data['options'];

      foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option['type'] == 'select') {
           echo $option['products_option_value_id'];
           echo $option['name'];
        }
      }
```

Thank you

To display the value products_option_value, I must write inside the array

```
$data['options'][] = [
           'products_option_value' => $product_option_value_data[0]
        ];
```

`[0]` is not the only value, I can have other see above

result :

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '213' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=9)
          'products_option_value_id' => string '171' (length=3)
          'option_value_id' => string '179' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
          'image' => null
          'price' => string '&nbsp;0.20&nbsp;EUR' (length=19)
          'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
          'customers_group_id' => null
          'products_option_model' => null
          'option_tax_class_id' => null
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '212' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=9)
          'products_option_value_id' => string '171' (length=3)
          'option_value_id' => string '179' (length=3)
          'name' => string 'S' (length=1)
          'image' => null
          'price' => string '&nbsp;0.20&nbsp;EUR' (length=19)
          'price_prefix' => string '+' (length=1)
          'customers_group_id' => null
          'products_option_model' => null
          'option_tax_class_id' => null
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
```

else I have that.

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '213' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=13)
          0 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          3 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          5 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          6 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          7 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          8 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          9 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          10 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          11 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          12 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'products_option_id' => string '212' (length=3)
      'products_option_value' => 
        array (size=13)
          0 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          1 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          2 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          3 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          4 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          5 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          6 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          7 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          8 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          9 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          10 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          11 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          12 => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
      'option_id' => string '40' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Taille' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'select' (length=6)
      'value' => null
      'required' => null
```

Comment: Is the first foreach closed correctly? As I think that `$data['options'][]` is outside foreach

Comment: @AhmadRezkyes it's correct $product_option_value_data take the element of the loop

Comment: Have you tried to use `key => value` instead?
Like this: 
`foreach ($options as $k => $option) {`

Comment: @AhmadRezk  yes, same result

Comment: Can u dump `$data['options']`?

Comment: @AhmadRezk i inserted the comment about $data['options']

Comment: I think u don't need to initialize `$data['options']` with an empty array. Try removing this line `$data['options'] = [];`